# Puppeteer - Cannot target specific drop-down menu element

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Problem:** I am trying to use Puppeeteer to use `await page.click(<ELEMENT>);` to change the currency in the drop down menu of a website [ihg hotel](https://www.ihg.com/hotels/us/en/find-hotels/hotel-search?qDest=Seattle,%20Washington,%20United%20States&qPt=CASH&qCiD=17&qCoD=19&qCiMy=92023&qCoMy=92023&qAdlt=1&qChld=0&qRms=1&qRtP=6CBARC&qAAR=6CBARC&srb_u=1&qSrt=sAV&qBrs=6c.hi.ex.sb.ul.ic.cp.cw.in.vn.cv.rs.ki.ma.sp.va.re.vx.nd.sx.we.lx.rn.sn&qWch=0&qSmP=0&qRad=30&qRdU=mi&setPMCookies=false&qpMn=0).

I am getting `Error: Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement`.

[image: ihg ss]

Code I've tried that all didn't work below:

```
await page.click('div[class^="ui-dropdown-label-container"] label[class^="ng-tns"]');

await page.click('app-currency-selector [class="theme-dropdown"] p-dropdown[class^="ng-tns"]');

await page.click('p-dropdown[aria-label="Currency Selector"]');

await page.click('app-currency-selector[class="theme-dropdown"] p-dropdown[aria-label="Currency Selector"] class^="ng-tns-c84-9"');
```

Comment: Did you try the usual click hack, `page.$eval("selector", el => el.click())`? Also, I'm assuming you waited for the element. In general, avoid `[class="foo"]` selectors--they fail if other classes are present or the order changes. Prefer `.foo`. The exception is if you're using an anchor like `^=` or you have too many results and need to increase precision. The last selector looks syntactically incorrect because `class^="ng-tns-c84-9"` would need `[]` around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there can be two variants why this is happened to you.

1. Your site is rendered in mobile view (as for me by default), and on it dropdown selector exists in DOM, but actually it is invisible.
2. After opening dropdown you don't wait for dropdown options container visibility.

For first case you need to maximize window and set viewport like

```js
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: ['--start-maximized']
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 2000, height: 1368});
```

If you have second issue, you should wait for at least one dropdown option to exist and only then init `ElementHandle` array and click on it

```js
    await page.waitForSelector('.theme-dropdown .ui-dropdown-label-container');
    await page.$$('.theme-dropdown .ui-dropdown-label-container').then(els => els[2].click()); // 2 is index of currency dropdown
    await page.waitForSelector('p-dropdownitem');
    await page.$$('p-dropdownitem').then(el => el[2].click()); // select 3rd currency option
```

Also, I have lots of methods in my [library](https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai) for working with dropdowns.

Example:

```js
import { getElements, selectDropdownOptionByTextExactMatch } from 'bubanai-ng';

    const dropdowns = await getElements(page, '.theme-dropdown .ui-dropdown-label-container', {shouldBeNotEmpty: true});
    const currencyDropdown = dropdowns[2];
    await selectDropdownOptionByTextExactMatch(page, currencyDropdown, 'p-dropdownitem', 'DOP'); // this line selects currency DOP
```

[Reference to dropdown utils](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/modules/src.html#selectdropdownoptionbytextexactmatch)